# USB communications device class support in Android gingerbread or ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, usb, cdc, usbserial

Starting with Android 3.1, Android devices have limited host support. I have reviewed
android.hardware.usb, and I have found very limited references to USB CDC support.  I have a self-powered peripheral USB device, that communicates using USB CDC serial.  I would like to connect it to an Android phone operating as a host, and read and write to it.

I would prefer to interface using Gingerbread, but could live with Ice Cream sandwich.  I have seen posts that discuss this using custom ROMs, and rooted phones, but that is not an option for me.

Is USB CDC serial supported in Android 3.1 or 4.0?  If so, are there any good code examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are right, Android API does not come with a class driver for CDC.

Have a look at these two libraries:

- [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)
- [physicaloid](https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary)